# Using Python to return elevation at arbitrary XY, from contour vector file

Tags: python, elevation

I want to write a Python3 script to calculate the elevation difference between a 3D surface (supplied as a DXF of contours) and a long list of XYZ coordinates (supplied as a CSV).  The script should have a minimal requirement for additional modules or installed applications.

The logical steps are easy:

- Import one or more suitable Python modules such as GDAL or GeoPandas
- Write a function `elevation(X,Y)` to return an elevation at a given XY coordinate.  This might have a prerequisite such as generating a vector TIN or a raster DEM.  For speed, generalizing the contour layer might also be a useful pre-process.
- Open the contour DXF and perhaps post-process it to provide the "feed" needed for the `elevation` function
- Loop through the data from the CSV, outputting the elevation difference for each row.

I'm having problems finding a way to do this job.  Research keeps leading to graphical GIS environments, which should not be necessary.

Comment: It looks like GDAL is not going to be able to read the 3D values from the DXF - see the 3d extensibility section here:  https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html.